# Mysterious very small rectangle box with "x" in the middle shows up but cannot be located anywhere on the DOM

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dom

I have this small approx. 2px x 5px rectangle with "x" through it that is showing up on tablet and mobile devices but not on desktop. It's no where on the DOM, and I don't know how or why it's being rendered.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this rectangle/box with "x" through it?[image]

Comment: can you reproduce it for us with some code?

Comment: i`m sure it is a "charset" issue.

Comment: may be something is still loading...some `fonts` maybe

Comment: can we see the webpage (via URL) or the html code? it is definitely a charset issue.

Comment: This looks like a :before or :after content:"" problem where a specific character is chosen than can not be displayed. Further code is required to actually find the problem at hand!

Comment: Sure here is the website url: 

https://www.investability.com/Featured-Listing/Indianapolis/46202/Indiana/17660314/details

You can't see the issue on iPhone only Android devices. It will be in the "TurnKey Services" Block

Comment: When you look at the page source (ctrl-u) at line 1136 you see this char [LSEP]</section>

Is that intentionally there?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an encoded character, like when you copy/paste from Word. Try removing all spaces in your block or text.